# Closing as duplicates for migrated questions.

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates, migration

This is mostly an announcement in case anyone wondered what happened to these two questions:

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98121
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98162

Question 2 was asked at StackOverflow, which bounced it to us. Question 1 was asked (by presumably the same user, given the same user handle) here. Because of the nature of the migration, Question 2 was orphaned in the sense that it had no owners and noone could accept an answer, despite it having received several. Questions 1 was closed as duplicate of Question 2.

So...

I re-opened question 1, closed question 2 as a duplicate of question 1, and merged question 2 into question 1. So if the question owner wanted to, he/she can accept one of the given answers.

Now...

for future reference, if you are voting to close a question as an **exact duplicate** of a question **without an owner**, please also flag for moderator attention so a similar procedure may be implemented if it is appropriate.